# Как правильно проверить ЭП в Java?

Tags: java, криптография, валидация, цифровая-подпись

У меня есть 2 файла - файл подписи(PKCS7) и файл, который был этой подписью подписан. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как можно проверить, что подпись действительно относится к этому файлу? Я думаю тут такая последовательность действий..:

1. Проверяем не истек ли срок действия сертификата
2. Проверяем все ли нормально с УЦ
3. Проверяем не отозван ли публичный ключ подписанта
4. И, наконец, достаем хеш из файла(именно достаем по коду внутри файла, а не получаем от всего файла) и сравниваем его с хешем подписанного файла, если все хорошо - проверка прошла.

Поправьте меня, если я не прав.. У меня вот только один вопрос - как все это реализовать в Java? Нашел хорошую библиотеку Bouncy Castle, только вот пользоваться ей дальше, кроме кода ниже, не нашел.

```
CMSSignedData pkcs7 = new CMSSignedData(bytesArray)
```

Там есть прикольные методы, типо пробежаться по сертификату, получить какие-нибудь данные по OI, но самой проверки я что-то найти не могу. Аж самому пришлось метод isBetween писать, который проверяет не истек ли сертификат. А как уж реализовать пункты 2 и 3 я уж совсем не представляю... Помогите, люди добрые.

Comment: В общем получилось извлечь значение хеша из messageDigest и сравнить с прогнанным через ГОСТ'овский алгоритм хеширования файлом, который был подписан. Но мне кажется, этого недостаточно. Моя цель сейчас - пройтись по всем сертификатам и убедиться, что с ними все хорошо. Сертификат подписанта получается извлечь, а как извлечь рутовые сертификаты и проверить их? И еще вопрос - нужно ли мне вообще трогать саму подпись для проверки?

Comment: В общем, нужно будет еще проверить весь chain сертификатов от корневого до юзерского. Как это сделать? И как проверить валидность сертификата, что он действительно был выдан Минкомсвязи или кем там нормальным?